# Use of relational operators when reading a file from CMD

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to create a command line program which outputs numbers from a file only greater than (larger than) specified one.
Say like there's a file output.txt with lots of numbers (one per line) and I need to get the only ones less than 5000.

Here's a part of my code, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
CHOICE /C 12

SET /P Comparative_number="Input a number: "

IF %ErrorLevel%==2 GOTO LESS_OPERATION

FOR /F %%A IN (%OutputFile%) DO IF %%A GTR %Comparative_number% ECHO %%A

ECHO. & ECHO End of output & EXIT /B

:LESS_OPERATION

FOR /F %%A IN (%OutputFile%) DO IF %%A LSS %Comparative_number% ECHO %%A

ECHO. & ECHO End of output & EXIT /B
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command extensions are enabled by default. But if a batch script depends on command extensions as when using `GTR` and `LSS` in an **IF** condition is always advisable to enable them explicitly.

The integer numbers must be listed in the file referenced via environment variable `OutputFile` line by line, for example:

```
50
23
478
-3425
9071
```

A batch code which worked:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
SET "OutputFile=C:\Temp\File With Numbers Listed Line By Line.txt"

ECHO.
ECHO Please choose the comparison:
ECHO.
ECHO 1 ... Greater Than
ECHO 2 ... Smaller Than
ECHO.
CHOICE /C:12 /N /M "Your choice: "
ECHO.

SET "Comparative_number=0"
SET /P "Comparative_number=Input a number: "
ECHO.
IF %ErrorLevel%==2 GOTO LESS_OPERATION

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ("%OutputFile%") DO IF %%A GTR %Comparative_number% ECHO %%A
ECHO.
ECHO End of output
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B

:LESS_OPERATION
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ("%OutputFile%") DO IF %%A LSS %Comparative_number% ECHO %%A
ECHO.
ECHO End of output
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B
```

Why your code does not work in comparison to this slightly modified code depends most likely on name of output file, how the numbers are listed in output file and how you have used command **CHOICE**.

Comment: Thank you so much! The edited code works flawlessly.